# Constants for the Brachistochrone Curve

Tags: calculus, geometry

Bernoulli showed using the physics of light that the equation of the Brachistochrone is

$$ \frac{\sin \theta}{\sqrt{y}} = C$$

which is the equation of a cycloid. One can write the equation of a cycloid parametrically as

$$\begin{aligned} x &= r ( t - \sin t ) \\ y &= r (1 - \cos t) \end{aligned} \tag{A}$$

If I have a line, say $y=-x$, and two points $A$ and $B$ on said line, how do I determine the value of $C$ or $r$ such that the resulting cycloid gives the shortest travel time between $A$ and $B$? Is there only one such solution ? Playing around on Desmos, I noticed that for any given r, there seems to exist $\theta$ s.t. if I rotate the cycloid given above by (A) by $\theta$, I get a cycloid that passes through both points A and B. Will all these cycloids give the same minimal travel time between A and B? I don't think so because as r becomes very large, you can get a cycloid which passes through A and B but which between A and B is almost a straight line. However, I'm not sure how to find the exact equation for the cycloid which is the brachistochrone, or how to show that this cycloid is unique, (if it is unique, as intuition suggests). I would prefer an answer that avoids the use of calculus of variations if possible.

Comment: Unfortunately there's no neat way to determine the specific constants of the parametric equation given the 2 points A and B, which is typical of nonlinear systems such as the eqns of motion for the brachistocrone.

Comment: One can show that under all infinitly many $C^1$ brachistochronic paths the cycloid is the only $C^2$- path and this path is unique.